# Inserting git commit date without hooks

Tags: packages, revision-control, git

Is there a way to insert the last git commit date into a document without having to add git hooks (like the gitinfo package does it)?

I'm not 100% sure how LaTeX packages work, but if they can access the current directory during compile-time and if they can execute external commands, that should easily be possible...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**I ended up using a custom Makefile to insert the revision info.**

When creating a Makefile instead of using the `--enable-write18` compiler flag, you require people to use a specific compilation method. That sucks. But the same thing counts for write18, as people have to configure their compiler to allow possibly insecure access to their system. By using a Makefile, the security risk of write18 is reduced, while providing an almost cross-platform method of compiling your document (`Make` is available when using cygwin on Windows; cygwin usually comes with git anyways). To (intelligently) compile the document itself, you can use *latexmk* on Linux and OS X (comes with TeXLive) and *texify* on Windows (comes with MiKTeX).

This is the Makefile:

```
TARGET=main.pdf
LL=latexmk -pdf
CLEAN=latexmk -C

all: revision.tex $(TARGET)

pdf: revision.tex $(TARGET)

.PHONY : clean revision.tex $(TARGET)

revision.tex:
    echo "% Autogenerated, do not edit" > revision.tex
    echo "\\newcommand{\\revisiondate}{`git log -1 --format=\"%ad\" --date=short`}" >> revision.tex
    echo "\\newcommand{\\revision}{`git log -1 --format=\"%h\"`}" >> revision.tex

$(TARGET): $(TARGET:%.pdf=%.tex) $(SRC)
    $(LL) $<

clean:
    $(CLEAN)
    rm -f revision.tex
```

If people want to build the PDF directly from their favorite IDE, they can tell the IDE to trigger "make". This should work with most software. When you use vim for example, you can use a mapping like this:

```
map <leader>m :w<CR> :!make<CR><CR>
```

The Makefile creates a file called `revision.tex` which looks like this:

```
% Autogenerated, do not edit
\newcommand{\revisiondate}{2012-10-17}
\newcommand{\revision}{e8e5238}
```

To insert it into the main document, simply use `\input{revision}` and then insert `\revisiondate` or `\revision` at the desired place.

Comment: I would say you would be better of using the gitinfo2 package. Even when you don‘t want to use git hooks you still can call the post-xxx-sample.txt script from your makefile.

Comment: it looks like the make file needs more escaping of \\

Comment: A better command for the revision might `git describe --always --tags`.

Answer (score 26):

[image]

This is `svn` but any command line is the same.

Depending on your configuration you probably need

```
pdflatex --enable-write18 filename
```

to enable `\write18` to be a hook to execute shell commands.

this writes to a temporary file using the shell escape, then inputs it

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\immediate\write18{svn info \jobname.tex | grep "Changed Date" > \jobname.info }
\fbox{\input{\jobname.info}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works (although the configuration might be a little annoying depending on the software used) :)

Comment: Corresponding git write18 command could be: `\write18{git log -1 --format="\@percentchar ad" --date=short > \jobname.info}`

Comment: `\immediate\write18{git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h%x3b%ad" --date=short > \jobname.info}` this is the line I'm using for git at the moment.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative solution that runs with `gitinfo2`. Hence I really like `gitinfo2`; the hooks mechanism proposed never satisfied me.

I ended up doing Makefile and shell scripts, but they weren't properly handled by my LaTeX editor and were not working on all platforms.

Finally, I ended up writing a kind of plugin for `latexmk`.

This plugin is named `gitinfo2-latexmk` and is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/rbarazzutti/gitinfo2-latexmk)

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that plugin.

The setup is pretty easy :

- download the *plugin* `gitinfo2.pm` (Perl module)
- add one line in your `.latexmkrc` file

Once these two small steps are done, no more boilerplate is needed. Each time you, or your LaTeX editor, run `latexmk`, the git information is ready for the package `gitinfo2`.

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution:
use \write18 to write a temp.dat file which contains 2 commands:

```
\gdef\GITHash{...}
\gedf\GITDate{...}
```

then input that file, the `\GITxxx` will get defined. We can use it anywhere, e.g. running title.

```
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{git log -1 --pretty=format:"\@backslashchar gdef\@backslashchar GITHash{\@percentchar h}\@percentchar n \@backslashchar gdef\@backslashchar GITDate{\@percentchar ad}" --date=short > /tmp/temp.dat }
\makeatother
\input{/tmp/temp.dat}
\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [Danilo's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78089/176708) approach, but I'm using a makefile on windows, so it took some tweaks to get the revision file to be created.

I'm sharing it for anyone's benefit and to improve upon:

```
revision.tex:
    powershell "echo '\newcommand{\revisiondate}{' | Out-File revision.tex -NoNewLine -Encoding UTF8"
    powershell 'git log -1 --format="%ad" --date=short | Out-File revision.tex -Append -NoNewLine -Encoding UTF8'
    powershell "echo '}' | Out-File source\_revision.md -Append -Encoding UTF8"
    powershell "echo '\newcommand{\revision}{' | Out-File revision.tex -Append -NoNewLine -Encoding UTF8"
    powershell "git describe --always --tags | Out-File revision.tex -Append -NoNewLine -Encoding UTF8"
    powershell "echo '}' | Out-File revision.tex -Append -Encoding UTF8"
```