# How to include the current Git commit ID and branch in my document?

Tags: revision-control, git, gitinfo

I use Git to track changes on my TEX files. When producing a PDF, it would be nice to include the current branch and commit ID somewhere in the document (e.g. on the title page or in a footer).

I know that the package [gitinfo2](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/gitinfo2/gitinfo2.pdf) exists but I'd rather avoid adding any hooks to Git. Besides, I am aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75336/inserting-git-commit-date-without-hooks) but I would prefer a solution that does not require enabling `\write18`.

Given that the name of the current branch can be found in `.git/HEAD` and the current commit ID is stored in `.git/refs/heads/[name of branch]`, is it possible to embed this information in the final document?

Comment: I'm writing this self-answered Q&A because it took me a while to figure this out. Hope it will help others in the future.

Comment: despite the question saying you wanted an alternative to gitinfo, there is a big overlap so I added that tag

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As stated in the question, the branch name can be extracted from `.git/HEAD` and given `[branch name]`, the commit ID can be found in `.git/refs/heads/[branch name]`.

The package [`catchfile`](https://ctan.org/pkg/catchfile) provides the command `\CatchFileDef`, which allows us to read `.git/HEAD` into a macro. As `HEAD` has no file extension, MiKTeX users have to [add a trailing dot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128364/37118) to the file name:

```
\CatchFileDef{\headfull}{.git/HEAD.}{}
```

This assigns something like `ref: refs/heads/master`  to `\headfull`. As this string has a trailing whitespace character, we use `\StrGobbleRight` from the [xstring](https://ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package to trim it:<sup>1</sup>

```
\StrGobbleRight{\headfull}{1}[\head]
```

In order to extract only the branch name (`master` in the example) from this string, we can use `\StrBehind`:

```
\StrBehind[2]{\head}{/}[\branch]
```

This saves the branch name in `\branch`. Finally, we can use `\CatchFileDef` again, to save the commit ID in `\commit`:

```
\CatchFileDef{\commit}{.git/refs/heads/\branch.}{}
```

There are some edge cases where `.git/refs/heads/\branch.` does not exist: After running [`git pack-refs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs) (which is a side effect of [`git gc --aggressive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#_aggressive), for example), the heads are packed into the file `.git/packed-refs` instead of individual `branchname` files. As a workaround, check if the file exists before trying to read it:

```
\IfFileExists{.git/refs/heads/\branch.}{%
    \CatchFileDef{\commit}{.git/refs/heads/\branch.}{}}{%
    \newcommand{\commit}{\dots~(in \emph{packed-refs})}}
```

As a fallback, this creates the (not-so-useful) output "... (in *packed-refs*)" instead of a commit ID – but this only lasts until the next commit, when the file `heads/branchname` is recreated for the affected branch.
(A more ambitious workaround could parse `packed-refs`, of course.)

## Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\CatchFileDef{\headfull}{.git/HEAD.}{}
\StrGobbleRight{\headfull}{1}[\head]
\StrBehind[2]{\head}{/}[\branch]
\IfFileExists{.git/refs/heads/\branch.}{%
    \CatchFileDef{\commit}{.git/refs/heads/\branch.}{}}{%
    \newcommand{\commit}{\dots~(in \emph{packed-refs})}}

\begin{document}
This revision: \texttt{\commit} on branch \texttt{\branch}.
\end{document}
```

### Sample output:

> This revision: `d92dc1386e48e04ceecb85461ed3b232146e6a32` on branch
> `master`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Using the last optional argument of `\StrGobbleRight` (`name`) to assign the trimmed string to a macro (`\head`) is necessary to allow further manipulation of the string using the `xstring` functions – see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/254275/37118) for a discussion.

Comment: Is it correct that `catchfile` is currently a no-go with `lualatex`?

Comment: Sorry, I've never been using lualatex yet.

Comment: I am using `catchfile` successfully with `lualatex` right now. The documentation states: _[2007/11/11 v1.2] Use of package pdftexcmds for LuaTEX support._

Comment: I really like this solution. would you mind editing in a way to escape underscores in branch names? ot should I pose a new question for this?

Comment: @ingli I didn't test this yet, but I think you should be able to modify the approach [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20891/37118).

Comment: Is it me, or with this solution the document revision will always be one commit behind the one where the document currently lives?

Comment: @SeF It (still) works for me. Would you mind sharing a reproducible example, maybe even a minimal Github repository?

Comment: @CL. thanks for the reply. It is just about how the pipeline works: 
**(1)** compile the latex source code: the pdf is tagged with hash 1234 and my-branch 
**(2)** `git commit -am "another commit"` (now the git hash of the latest commit is 5678)
**(3)** `git pull my-branch`
**(Now)** If I am not wrong, on the repo the latest hash is `5678`, while on the pdf document on the repo the hash is still `1234`.

Comment: @SeF Yes, I think I see your problem. But I'd say this is "natural": You need to commit etc. *before* you compile. … … Ok, now I think I understand: You're commiting the PDF as well? Agreed, this won't work. But IMHO, you should "gitignore" the PDF anyway and only commit the source files. And then the problem should become a non-issue automatically. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

A no-package approach (tested on mac os, modify it for Windows regarding extra needed dot perhaps) based on @CL.'s answer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\dotGitHEAD{}
\newcommand\branch{}
\newcommand\commit{}


\makeatletter\let\myfilehandle\@inputcheck\makeatother

\openin\myfilehandle=.git/HEAD\relax

\begingroup\endlinechar-1
  \global\read\myfilehandle to \dotGitHEAD
\endgroup
\closein\myfilehandle

\newcommand\GetBranch{}
\def\GetBranch ref: refs/heads/#1\relax{\renewcommand{\branch}{#1}}

\expandafter\GetBranch\dotGitHEAD\relax

\openin\myfilehandle=.git/refs/heads/\branch\relax

\begingroup\endlinechar-1
  \global\read\myfilehandle to \commit
\endgroup
\closein\myfilehandle

\begin{document}
\branch+++

\commit+++

This revision: \texttt{\commit} on branch \texttt{\branch}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

Package `getcommit`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{getcommit}[2018/10/16 get current commit and branch (JFB)]

\@ifundefined{branch}{}
   {\PackageWarning{getcommit}{ATTENTION!^^J
    \@spaces\@spaces\string\branch\space macro was already
    defined. Overwritten.}}
\@ifundefined{commit}{}
   {\PackageWarning{getcommit}{ATTENTION!^^J
    \@spaces\@spaces\string\commit\space macro was already
    defined. Overwritten.}}

\openin\@inputcheck=.git/HEAD\relax

\begingroup\endlinechar-1
  \global\read\@inputcheck to \getcommit@HEAD
\endgroup
\closein\@inputcheck

\def\getcommit@GetBranch ref: refs/heads/#1\relax{\def\branch{#1}}

\expandafter\getcommit@GetBranch\getcommit@HEAD\relax

\openin\@inputcheck=.git/refs/heads/\branch\relax

\begingroup\endlinechar-1
  \global\read\@inputcheck to \commit
\endgroup
\closein\@inputcheck
\endinput
```

Example of use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{getcommit}

\begin{document}
+++\branch+++

+++\commit+++

%\frenchspacing
This revision: \texttt{\commit} on branch \texttt{\branch}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there an available scratch file handle for read operations in LaTeX, avoiding a `\newread` here?

Comment: There is `\@inputcheck` used by the kernel in \IfFileExists.

Comment: Quite nice and it works on windows. But imho for a real package it should try to find the info also in parent folders (imho gitinfo2 looks 4 levels up by default).

Comment: But miktex really needs the period at the end ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is there any test allowing package to know that this is executed under MikTeX?

Comment: I think there was somewhere a test but can't remember now. But the syntax with the dot works for me also with texlive. So if it fails on linux one would need only to test for windows (ifplatform).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it fails on mac os x and I expect also on linux. quick look at `ifplatform` seems to indicate it does not need shell escape for `\ifwindows` so this is good, but add a dependency to my tiny package...

Comment: yes this slightly different handling of unusual file names is rather a pain.

Comment: a package should also have options `[commitmacro=\commit, branchmacro=\branch]` for example.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `\input` instead `\read` primitive:

```
\def\gitdir{.git/}
\def\readgitcommitA #1 {\def\gitcommit{#1}}
\def\readgitbranchA #1 #2 {\def\gitbranch{#2}}
\def\readgitcommit{\expandafter\readgitbranchA \input \gitdir HEAD
  \expandafter\readgitcommitA \input \gitdir\gitbranch\relax}

\readgitcommit

Now, the commit ID is in "\gitcommit" macro.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `latexmk`,
you can use an alternative approach to intialize `gitinfo2`,
that does **not** require git hooks (https://github.com/rbarazzutti/gitinfo2-latexmk).

Setup:

```sh
$ git submodule add https://github.com/rbarazzutti/gitinfo2-latexmk gitinfo2-latexmk
$ echo "do './gitinfo2-latexmk/gitinfo2.pm';" >> latexmkrc
```

Usage:

```tex
\usepackage[mark]{gitinfo2}
```